# Python. How to find a point on the timeline where Fcurve reaches a certain value without changing current subframe?

Tags: python, keyframes, timeline, fcurves

Is there any way to find out via Python at which point of the Timeline (at which subframe) fcurve reaches a certain value, without actually changing the current subframe? I have found out that it was possible to get certain `keyframe_points` coordinates on the timeline, but is there any way to analyze the whole fcurve somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using `FCurve.evaluate(frame)` and `numpy`**

In this related [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/190349/15543) have found the minimum of an fcurve based on 0.01 subframe increments, instead here will find the first point where the fcurve is greater than a given value.

Test script, loops over all actions and prints the frame (and value) where it first exceeds value.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

value = 10

frames = np.arange(1, 250, 0.01)

for action in bpy.data.actions:
    print(f"{action.name}")
    
    for fc in action.fcurves:
        print(f"{fc.data_path}[{fc.array_index}]")
        points = np.vectorize(fc.evaluate)(frames)

        hit = np.where(points > value)[0]
        if hit.size:
            f = hit[0]

            print(f"{frames[f]} : value {points[f]}")
```

Comment: Thank you! `FCurve.evaluate(frame)` is exactly what I was looking for!