# Why does keyframe_delete() seem to call keyframe_insert()?

Tags: python, animation

I am writing a script to offset some animations of subsequent objects from an array.

The idea is that I will take the 'old' keyframe data, add some number to it, then insert the 'new' keyframe with the updated data.

```py
import bpy

active_obj = bpy.context.active_object

tracks = active_obj.animation_data.nla_tracks 

for track in tracks:
    for strip in track.strips:
        action = strip.action

        for fcu in action.fcurves:
            data_path = fcu.data_path  # Name of parameter
            for keyframe in fcu.keyframe_points:
                old_keyframe = keyframe.co
                new_keyframe = (old_keyframe.x + 2, old_keyframe.y + 2)
                
                fcu.keyframe_delete(data_path, 0, old_keyframe.x)
```

When I run this code, I get the error: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "X:\path\to\file\offset.py", line 17, in <module> TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "location" not found`.

My scene is just a single cube that goes from Location Z=9 to Location Z=1 over 30 frames, but I can provide the blend file if you need that.

I'm unsure why it is trying to run `keyframe_insert()` when I am not referencing it at all in my script..

Also, I am using Blender 2.93

Documentation for [keyframe_delete()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_delete)

Comment: The `keyframe_insert` and `keyframe_delete` are methods on blender object properties s that can be animated, . for example the `location` property of the "Cube".  An fcurve has neither a `location` property (the error message), nor can it be animated.  Suggest if you wish to shift the z location keyframe, search for datapath and array index and  set that fcurves value with `keyframe.co.y += 2`  (The x part of a keyframe is the frame)

Comment: Ah, so you are saying that I should adjust the actual keyframe values instead of deleting and creating new ones? That makes a lot of sense here. Cheers man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using `foreach_get` and `foreach_set`**

The `keyframe_insert` and `keyframe_delete` are methods on blender object properties  that can be animated, . for example the `location` property of the "Cube".  On the default file with no animations, adding a keyframe to cube using `cube.keyframe_insert("location", 0, 1)` creates an action, creates an fcurve, inserts the keyframe, returns a boolean, `True` if successful.

An fcurve has neither a `location` property (the error message), nor can it be animated.  (It is the animation) Suggest if you wish to shift the z location keyframe, search for datapath and array index and set that fcurves value with `keyframe.co.y += 2` (The x part of a keyframe is the frame)

*Note: if the action is in the NLA then shifting the x (frame) can be done by setting the strip start. Adding to the value y, can be done via adding a simple action that is simply a constant*

Another thing to consider is the keyframe handles.

Here is a test script to shift all keyframes in an fcurve.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

def fcurve_shift(fcurve, shift=(0, 0), shift_handles=True):
    props = ("co", "handle_left", "handle_right") if shift_handles else ("co",) 
    for prop in props:
        kfps = np.empty(len(fcurve.keyframe_points) << 1)
        fcurve.keyframe_points.foreach_get(prop, kfps)
        kfps = kfps.reshape((2, -1)) + shift
        fcurve.keyframe_points.foreach_set(prop, kfps.ravel())
        

# test call

action = bpy.data.actions["CubeAction"]
for fc in action.fcurves:
    fcurve_shift(fc, (2, 2))
```

[Copying specific frames from one action to another ( python )](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214866/copying-specific-frames-from-one-action-to-another-python/214899)

[How to obtain max and min of f-curve in python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185818/how-to-obtain-max-and-min-of-f-curve-in-python/190349)

Comment: This looks really promising, thank you. Can you explain why you are bitshifting in the line `np.empty(len(fcurve.keyframe_points)`? That confuses me a bit. But this is way better than my loops haha.

Comment: Basically just doubling for x and y. The foreach methods require  a flat list.  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214510/15543 image has 4 r, g, b, a.. bit shifting is a squeak quicker than multiplying.